Is there a way of setting up fr1200 fingerprint reader with ASC2204C-D Access Controller?
I am trying to set up an access controller with existing FR1200 readers. Is it possible to intergrate between 2 vendors (Dahua and ZK) for communication between the reader and the access controller? I have tried setting up the RS485 protocol for the reader and the controller, but I am not able to enroll users on the controller.
